# UIView animatewithDuration - Remove Animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a recursive UIView animatewith duration: delegate to run an animation. When the view disappears I''m supposed to stop this animation. [self.view.layer removeAllAnimation] doesn't seem to help. ANy other means to stop animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the method [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] ?
You can check inside the completion block if the view has disappeared. If it hasn't - run one more animation iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This solution i came across is based on the UIObject. I added the UIObject to an NSMutableArray on starting the animation. When I leave that view call for [NSMutableArray * removeObject]; inside viewDidDisappear.